# Stage managed node

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

In the staging mode, weblogic copies the deployment to the stage directory of the cluster nodes.

However, if we copy a modified version of the application (.war) directly to the stage directory, and re-start the node - the new/modified version is not used. Weblogic continues to run the earlier version of the application.

Is it possible to have a managed node run the application by copying directly to the 'stage' directory of the node?  We are using weblogic 10.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Development Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/autodeploy.html) you do have the option to copy in new files and have them auto deployed:

"*To auto-deploy an archived application, copy its archive file to the /autodeploy directory.     WebLogic Server automatically sets the application’s deployment mode to stage mode.*

*A deployment unit that was auto-deployed can be dynamically redeployed while the server is 
running. To dynamically redeploy, copy the new version of the archive file over the existing file in the /autodeploy directory.*"

However, that is not the appropriate way to deploy an application in a production environment. In production you have a few options. You can call [weblogic deployer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/wldeployer.htm#DEPGD360) with the **update** parameter:

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://test:7001 -user weblogic
-password weblogic -update -name myapp.ear -upload 
-plan c:\localfiles\nuPlan.xml
```

Or you can simply login to the weblogic admin console:

```
Deployments -> select your deployment -> Click Update -> choose your new war file
```